# nginx redirect and rewrite going to root domain not full path

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm trying to redirect all traffic from `domainA` to `domainB/landing-page`. I *do not* wish to preserve the original URI, and users should ultimately arrive on absolute URL `https://domainB/landing-page`. My test configuration below does not redirect users to URI `/landing-page` and instead redirects them to the root URL at `https://domainB/`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domainA.com www.domainA.com;
    
    location ~ / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://www.domainB/landing-page redirect;
        #return 301 https://www.domainB/landing-page;
    }
}
```

I've tried both using `rewrite` and `return` (commented out) and neither make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

`return` is all that's needed for domain redirection, and you may need to listen on HTTPS or IP6 if users enter through that port/IP.

```
server {
  listen      80;
  listen [::]:80;             # ip6
  listen      443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;  # ip6

  server_name domainA www.domainA;
  ssl_certificate     /path/to/file/domainA.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/file/domainA.key;

  return https://domainB/landing-page;
}
```

Comment: Gave that a try, still seems to do the same thing unfortunately.

Comment: rewrote and provided full redirection example

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /somePage;
```

Test config

*redir.local* and *[www.redir.local](http://www.redir.local)* domains added to local **/etc/hosts** file

```
server {
    listen 192.168.0.1:80;
    server_name redirect.local www.redirect.local;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /somePage;
    location =/somePage {
        return 200 "Request uri: $uri \n/somePage location example output.\n";
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    }

}

$ nginx -s reload
```

Check with curl

```
$ curl www.redir.local
```

Output:

```
Request uri: /somePage
/somePage location example output.
```

**UPD1**

Or if you need 301 redirect, try something like:

```
...
location / {
  return 301 http://www.redir.local/somePage;
}
location =/somePage {
  return 200 "Request uri: $uri \n/somePage location example output.\n";
  add_header Content-Type text/plain;
}
...
```

in browser you will redirected to /somePage
[image]